# Startup script doesn't execute at startup

Tags: startup, cron, upstart

I have followed the tutorial [here](http://vairavanlaxman.com/blog/2010/06/start-no-ip-on-startup-in-ubuntu.html) that shows how to setup the No-ip update program to start at system startup.

I have done exactly as specified here, yet the program still doesn't start. Also, when I use `sudo service noip2 start` the service "noip2" isn't recognized.

How exactly can I take an arbitary script and set it to execute at startup. I have tried many tutorials about upstarts etc but none of them work. Thanks.

```
>     1. Execute the following commands at the Terminal sudo chmod 700 /usr/local/bin/noip2 chown root:root /usr/local/bin/noip2
> 
> 2. Now create a shell script called “noip2.sh” in the directory /etc/init.d
> #! /bin/sh
> # /etc/init.d/noip2.sh
> 
> # Supplied by no-ip.com
> # Modified for Debian GNU/Linux by Eivind L. Rygge 
> # corrected 1-17-2004 by Alex Docauer
> 
> # . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions # uncomment/modify for your killproc
> 
> DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/noip2 NAME=noip2
> 
> test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
> 
> case “$1″ in start) echo -n “Starting dynamic address update: “
> start-stop-daemon –start –exec $DAEMON echo “noip2.” ;; stop) echo -n
> “Shutting down dynamic address update:” start-stop-daemon –stop
> –oknodo –retry 30 –exec $DAEMON echo “noip2.” ;;
> 
> restart) echo -n “Restarting dynamic address update: “
> start-stop-daemon –stop –oknodo –retry 30 –exec $DAEMON
> start-stop-daemon –start –exec $DAEMON echo “noip2.” ;;
> 
> *) echo “Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}” exit 1 esac exit 0
> 
> 3. Now finally execute this command in Terminal: sudo update-rc.d noip2.sh defaults 90
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it in Ubuntu is probably just to use the Startup Applications tool. Put your script in wherever it needs to be, then specify the full path to it (For example, /home/conor/script.sh).

Hopefully that will run that script on startup. I use this to start my Thunderbird whenever I login.

Comment: Is that a GUI tool? I'm running the server variant of Ubuntu?

Comment: You're right, it is.

You should be able to use sudo update-rc.d script.sh defaults though.